# Javascript disabled for checkout

Tags: checkout, javascript, validation

Can a customer avoid sales tax during checkout if they turn off javascript in their browser? Does the State dropdown get validated?

Is there a built in solution?

Answer (score 2):

A user can't complete their checkout if they don't have javascript enabled, so there's no risk in having them avoid sales tax or skipping entering a state.

Comment: Ive had it happen a couple times where my state dropdown has full state names but the sales invoice thats generated after the sale has the two state abbreviation and no sales tax is charged.